# Keeping application state until the app is killed

Tags: android

I read many answers here on SO but they confused me even more, so here's my question:

I'm working on an app where each component of the app (Activities, Services...) need direct access to the application's license state (which is determined once when the application loads and held in a variable).

I wish to save that state somewhere in the app that will be the last to "survive" being killed by Android. I read in many places that saving state information in the Application instance is bad since it can be erased by the OS while other components will not be removed from the memory, but I don't know what the better alternative is. I also have to save that value in-memory **and not persist it to a file or the application's SharedPreferences** as it will become more susceptible to manual tampering.

My question is - what is the best place to keep that information until the entire process is killed?

Comment: Create a singleton class that extends application and have it hold your variables.

Comment: Your application instance stays active throughout your application lifecycle, so not sure what you mean by it can be erased by the OS (unless there's something I am unaware of which I'm always happen to learn).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are planning on doing is just "caching" some persisted state in your application class. In other words all you care about is that whatever instance of the application class you call getLicense() on, as long as it has gone through the `onCreate()` method,  it should have the correct information.

So if you are doing something like this I think you will be fine by "caching" the state in the application class.

```
private License mLicense;

@Override
public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate();
    mLicense = SomeProvider.getLicense();
}

public License getLicense() {
    return mLicense;
```

The problem with storing state in the Application class is that an activity can be resumed with a new / different instance of the application than when it was paused.  So if you save something from an activity to an object in an instance of the application class and expect to retrieve it from when the activity is resumed, that may not work.  A good explanation can be found [here](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of an Activity or Service by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`. You write your data to the `Bundle` parameter which is passed to this method. When the Activity or Service is recreated, you can load the information from the `Bundle` which is passed to `onCreate()`.